# Django save() a form if user selects "Save" button, and save(commit=false) if user selects "Calculate" button

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms

I would like to save a form to the database if user selects "Save" button and return to list view, and save(commit=false) if user selects "Calculate" button and stay on the now updated detail view.  I have some code that executes when the model is saved and I would like the user to be able to update the results without writing to the database by clicking "Calculate".  if they are happy with the updates, then they can click "Save" button and it writes to database.

Here is the model:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.propStartBalance = self.some_calc()
        self.propAvgResidual = self.some_other_calc()
        super(Proposal, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is view:

```
class ProposalUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Proposal
    context_object_name = "proposal_update"
    template_name = 'proposal/proposal_create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('proposal_list')
    form_class = ProposalForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.proposalOwnerID = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def save(self,commit=True):
        propInstance = super().save(commit= False)
        if 'calculateButton' in self.request.POST:
            commit = False

        if commit:
            propInstance.save()
        
        return propInstance
```

If the user selects "Calculate" I would like the model code to execute and the detail template to stay on screen with the new value.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I realize now that this can be done by just laying things out with the correct forms & views.  I was trying to do everything at once in a single view, much easier if I just bake it into the Views>Urls>Form/Templates.